# Uncomfortable workplace temperature

Tags: work-environment, productivity

Recently our department has relocated to a smaller office with access to A/C and Heat controls out in the open.

The temperature is normally set ~74F, but a handful of employees continue to turn off the unit, so the temperature rises to 78-82F.

Usually 3-4 times a day I turn the unit back on because it is grossly warm in the office, and with no air movement you are able to smell the bathrooms (which are single person stalls very close to all desks)

What is the best way to solve this problem, and keep the office at a nice ambient temperature?

For reference it is currently 70F outside today.

Comment: Offices should be ventilated (personally I hate A/C and all the sanitary issues it involves, so I just put the A/C on Fan Mode). If you feel cold, put your jacket on, if you feel warm take it off. That way everyone can regulate their temperature to the one they prefer, without imposing a general temp level.

Comment: @GrayCygnus The issue is that I'm in summer wear - maybe I'm crazy, but wearing anything but that in the office would be nuts at this temperature.  One can only dress down so much.

Comment: It seems that it is a problem with your coworkers, rather than the AC itself. You should try reason with them so maybe you can come up with some sort of "accepted use" of the AC

Comment: @GrayCygnus I often hear a few of them saying how cold it is or how cold they are etc - I don't see how when it is currently 80 degrees in the office.

Comment: well hard to tell. I sometimes have a similar issue with my boss, as he loves to decrease the temperature a lot when he arrives. Funny thing, when he does that he immediately puts his jacket on... As you can see, this seems like a back and forth problem, that should be mediated and agreed on a standard temperature and AC usage (I would go to what most coworkers think, and put it in that setting)

Comment: @ICanHazUpvotzPleez Likely not - this post is about reaching an ambient temperature not adapting.  I could see if we didn't have AC or heat then it could be a dupe.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is not a bad question

Comment: @RichardU I'm not sure either - I'm also unsure why it is marked as a dupe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep on turning the unit whenever needed.

Also get yourself a desk fan for your own comfort.

It might be worth asking your co-workers why they keep turning off the A/C and seeing whether there's an alternative solution to their problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve this problem is to bring it up with management and have them make a decision as to what the temperature controls should be set at.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact is that when one is cold, one can cover up.

Keep turning it back on and point this out to management if anyone says anything. Your coworkers can bring a sweater or jacket to keep warm, you cannot take off your clothes if you are too hot.